# My discord bot fails to find my members as of today

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I coded a discord bot in python which worked until today. Today it fails to find the members of my server which is obviously a dealbreaker. To identify the point of failiure I coded the folowing test routine:

```
@bot.command(name='test', help='test stuff')
async def test(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)

    print("Test done")
```

This is the code i copied and pasted from the documentation and it should work as usual. Today I get the feedback:

```
Bot is ready. (=> this print command is generated on the startup of the bot)
Keeper of Keys#4019
Test done
```

Keeper of Keys is the name of the bot itself. So apparently the bot is able to find itself, but not the other members of the guild. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I strolled through the documentation and found the solution to the problem:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. I wasn't aware about this change